# Pull Request Denied Docker XMR-Stak Mining Monero on Raspberry

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

Trying to pull docker image of xmr-stak for my raspberry. Wondering if I'm missing something basic about the docker syntax.

```
$sudo docker run --rm -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g) --name fireice-uk/xmr-stak -v "$PWD":/mnt xmr-stak
```

```
Unable to find image 'xmr-stak:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for xmr-stak, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

I log in using docker log in and I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently xmr-stak does not support arm processors and thus won't run on a Raspberry PI.

Currently I am working on a Raspberry PI 3 optimized miner based on xmrig. It gives you about 8-9h/s without a fan. (The processor clock goes down to 600-800MHz because of the heat), I will share some details as soon as it is ready.